# How to display a pickerview in a Rhodes cross platform application?

Tags: android, iphone, cross-platform, rhodes, rhomobile

I wonder how may I display **pickerview** in a **Rhodes application**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through [**this**](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/bb-css) and found the solution :

```
<select name="uiformdemo[selectbox]">
                <option selected>Please select</option>
                <option value="apple">iPhone</option>
                <option value="android">Android</option>
                <option value="blackberry">BlackBerry</option>
                <option value="winmo">Windows Mobile</option>
            </select>
```

This will create pickerview having options **iphone**, **Android**, **Blackberry** and **Windows Mobile**.